# TypeError when parsing XML

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML file of metadata on dissertations and I'm trying to get the author name as a single string. Names in the XML look like this:

```
      <DISS_name>
        <DISS_surname>Clark</DISS_surname>
        <DISS_fname>Brian</DISS_fname>
        <DISS_middle/>
        <DISS_suffix/>
      </DISS_name>
```

All names have first and last names, but only some have middle names and/or suffixes. Here is my code:

```
    author_surname = record.find('DISS_authorship/DISS_author/DISS_name/DISS_surname').text.strip().title()
    author_fname = record.find('DISS_authorship/DISS_author/DISS_name/DISS_fname').text.strip().title()
    author_mname = record.find('DISS_authorship/DISS_author/DISS_name/DISS_middle')
    author_suffix = record.find('DISS_authorship/DISS_author/DISS_name/DISS_suffix')
    if author_mname is not None and author_suffix is not None:
        author_name = author_surname + ', ' + author_fname + author_mname.text + ', ' + author_suffix.text
    if author_mname is not None and author_suffix is None:
        author_name = author_surname + ', ' + author_fname + author_mname.text
    if author_mname is None and author_suffix is None:
        author_name = author_surname + ', ' + author_fname
```

Why am I getting this output and how can I fix it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bpclark2\pythonProject3\prqXML-to-dcCSV.py", line 185, in <module>
    author_name = author_surname + ', ' + author_fname + author_mname.text + author_suffix.text
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

Revised code:

```
    author_surname = record.find('DISS_authorship/DISS_author/DISS_name/DISS_surname').text.strip().title()
    author_fname = record.find('DISS_authorship/DISS_author/DISS_name/DISS_fname').text.strip().title()
    author_mname = record.find('DISS_authorship/DISS_author/DISS_name/DISS_middle').text or ''
    author_suffix = record.find('DISS_authorship/DISS_author/DISS_name/DISS_suffix').text or ''
    author_name = author_surname + ', ' + author_fname + ' ' + str(author_mname.strip().title()) + str(', ' + author_suffix.strip().title())
    row.append(author_name)
```

This gets the output I was looking for:

```
    author_surname = record.find('DISS_authorship/DISS_author/DISS_name/DISS_surname').text.strip().title()
    author_fname = record.find('DISS_authorship/DISS_author/DISS_name/DISS_fname').text.strip().title()
    author_mname = record.find('DISS_authorship/DISS_author/DISS_name/DISS_middle').text or ''
    author_suffix = record.find('DISS_authorship/DISS_author/DISS_name/DISS_suffix').text or ''
    author_name = author_surname + ', ' + author_fname + ' ' + author_mname.strip().title() + ', ' + author_suffix.strip().title()
    if author_mname != '' and author_suffix != '':
        author_name = author_surname + ', ' + author_fname + ' ' + author_mname.strip().title() + ', ' + author_suffix.strip().title()
        row.append(author_name)
    if author_mname != '' and author_suffix == '':
        author_name = author_surname + ', ' + author_fname + ' ' + author_mname.strip().title()
        row.append(author_name)
    if author_mname == '' and author_suffix != '':
        author_name = author_surname + ', ' + author_fname + ', ' + author_suffix.strip().title()
        row.append(author_name)
    if author_mname == '' and author_suffix == '':
        author_name = author_surname + ', ' + author_fname
        row.append(author_name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd keep everything simple with just minor edits of code. You can use an XPath `.//DISS_name` to find all `<DISS_name>` nodes and then just unpack it into a separate variables with corresponding names. Code:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """\
<DISS_authorship>
    <DISS_author>
        <DISS_name>
            <DISS_surname>Clark</DISS_surname>
            <DISS_fname>Brian</DISS_fname>
            <DISS_middle/>
            <DISS_suffix/>
        </DISS_name>
    </DISS_author>
</DISS_authorship>"""

root = ET.fromstring(data)
row = []
for name_node in root.iterfind(".//DISS_name"):
    surname, fname, middle, suffix = name_node  # 4 child nodes in this order
    name_str = surname.text + ", " + fname.text
    if middle.text:
        name_str += " " + middle.text
    if suffix.text:
        name_str += ", " + suffix.text
    row.append(name_str)
```

Or even shorter:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = ...

root = ET.fromstring(data)
row = []
for (surname, fname, middle, suffix) in root.iterfind(".//DISS_name"):
    name_str = surname.text + ", " + fname.text
    if middle.text:
        name_str += " " + middle.text
    if suffix.text:
        name_str += ", " + suffix.text
    row.append(name_str)
```

Answer (score 2):

What about changing your code to something like this:

```
author_mname = record.find('DISS_authorship/DISS_author/DISS_name/DISS_middle') or ''
author_suffix = record.find('DISS_authorship/DISS_author/DISS_name/DISS_suffix') or ''
```

Also you could add `str` casts like:

```
... + str(author_suffix.text)
```

And if you are on new python please use f-strings! Life is much easier with them.

Comment: Thanks! I changed it to the revised code above based on your suggestion. The suffix needs to be separated by a comma, so I'm getting unnecessary commas, e.g, 'Clark, Brian,'

Answer (score 1):

A shorter concept below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml = '''<r><DISS_name>
        <DISS_surname>Clark</DISS_surname>
        <DISS_fname>Brian</DISS_fname>
        <DISS_middle/>
        <DISS_suffix/>
      </DISS_name>
      <DISS_name>
        <DISS_surname>Jack</DISS_surname>
        <DISS_fname>Brian</DISS_fname>
        <DISS_middle>Smith</DISS_middle>
        <DISS_suffix/>
      </DISS_name>
</r>'''
      
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for name in root.findall('.//DISS_name'):
  parts = [name.find(f'DISS_{f}').text for f in ['surname','fname','middle','suffix'] if name.find(f'DISS_{f}').text is not None ]
  print(", ".join(parts))
```

output

```
Clark, Brian
Jack, Brian, Smith
```

Comment: `fname` and `middle` should have just space between